# iOS UIButtons not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray

I am having a problem whereby I am adding images to a view, which has a parent(scrollView).
The problem is that although I am setting a selector for every button, only the most recently generated button in the view responds to the selector and calls the method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_wordsArray count]; i++) {

    buttonFrame = CGRectMake(WORDSLEFTBOUNDARY, heightPlacement, [_detailSlider value], [_detailSlider value]);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];

    // set the image for the button
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wordicon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:i]; // set tag identifier for the button

    // add selector method 'buttonClickedAction' so that the method is called when a user
    // clicks one of the buttons.
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [_buttonsView addSubview: button]; // add newly created button as a subview to the buttonView

    [_wordButtonArray addObject:button]; // insert newly created button into the wordButtonArray

    if (i < [_dateDifferences count]) {
        heightPlacement -= 60 + (60 * [[_dateDifferences objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
    }
}
```

So in the above code I create each button and add the selector before adding it to an array of buttons. However my responder method (buttonClickedAction) is not being called for some reason.

Comment: what is _buttonsView and self in this?

Comment: Guys - I've resolved to adding buttons directly to the scrollview for now as I need to test some functionality. It is working so far.

Answer (score 0):

For all the button you are setting the same frame `buttonFrame`.So buttons are added one above the other and the latest on the top .Hence the action of that button is only responding

Solution

- Log the button frame.

> NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(buttonFrame));

- Put a background image to make the buttons visible
- Give a seperate frame using itration value to make the buttons visible seperately
- Check the frame of _buttonsView and check it is visible in the view and make sure buttonsframe is a visible frame in _buttonsView

Use this to initialize the button

```
 UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:buttonFrame];
```

Last but not the least the action can be blocked by 2 reasons

1. The button is not in the visible frame of superview
2. some other view is on the top of the button

Comment: Sorry that wasnt the complete code - ive edited it to show the changes. I am not using the same frame so I'm not why the rest arent responding. I'm thinking maybe its something to do with the responder of a view?

Comment: Right sorry, I actually did change the frame already, copy/pasted wrong code. its changed at the top.

Comment: Insert that log where you init the button and please paste add the log to question

Comment: Still doesn't work. The log:
    '{{70, 910}, {50, 50}}'
    '{{70, 850}, {50, 50}}'
    '{{70, 730}, {50, 50}}'

Comment: Please check the points one by one any of it can be a reason.Log the frame of _buttonsView

Comment: The log of _buttonsView shows 335 (initialized earlier). 335 is much shorter than that of the scrollView, so how do I change it to match the scrollview? setBounds/setFrame don't appear to have any effect.

Comment: [_buttonsview setFrame:scrollView.bounds];

Comment: Is there a 'getter' for scrollView contentSize?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(scrollView.contentSize));// scrollView.contentSize:getter
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(10, 20)];//setter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe it's because your initWithFrame refers to a CGRect variable which constantly gets updated. Instead of using a variable, use CGRectMake directly inside initWithFrame

e.g.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(WORDSLEFTBOUNDARY, heightPlacement, [_detailSlider value], [_detailSlider value])];
```

Comment: i dont think so...buttonFrame is CGRect anyway and it doesnt change anything making it an oneliner

Comment: It's nothing to do with the frame - The images are all displaying in the correct place according to the frame. Its just the click that is not working. I've logged the button tags for each position and they are all there

Comment: Yeah I know, but saw you suggested they might have the same frame and thought this could be a reason why.

Comment: Some things I can think of are: 1- Are you sure there's nothing else overlaying rest of the buttons that might block your touch? 2- Are you sure the superview's frame contains all the buttons? Try adding 2 more or 2 less buttons and see which respond this time